# How to modify the tools.builde.gradle version to synchronize gradle

Tags: java, android, build, build.gradle

I have a problem and that is that when executing the following code

```
      ` <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="Iniciar seción"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />`
```

therefore modify the Build.gradle `classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` by the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`since this version works but now the problem is that the dradle project does not synchronize since I change the version, what can I do to solve this problem

Comment: post your build.gradle and your error